# Take Screenshot with Firefox

Tags: powershell, firefox, start-process

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out why this simple command is not working.

I'm attempting to take screenshots of a list of domains using PowerShell and Firefox per [this article][1].

Currently I have the following code, but it does not produce screenshots and I'm unsure what is wrong code wise. Any assistance and/or a point in the correct direction is greatly appreciated.

```
$screenshotdir = "$PSScriptRoot\FF_Screenshots"
If(!(Test-Path -Path $screenshotdir)) {New-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot -Name "FF_Screenshots" -ItemType Directory}

    function getFireFoxScreenShot() {
        $importedCSV = Import-Csv .\Domains.csv

        foreach ($url in $importedCSV) {
            $domainName = $url.Name #example google.com
            $domain = $url.Domain #example google (no tld)
            if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($domainName))){       
                Echo "Getting Screen Shot for: $domainName"
                Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " -ArgumentList " --screenshot $screenshotdir\$domain.png ", "$domainName" -Wait            
            }
       }
    }
    getFireFoxScreenShot

[1]: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/chrome-and-firefox-can-take-screenshots-of-sites-from-the-command-line/
```

Comment: What's ```$screenshotdir``` set to?

Comment: Is there any output from the console?

Comment: hello there, currently I can't test any solution regarding firefox. But try to use the cmd code from the article.
Then build it together as a String and do this:
Invoke-Expression $CmdLine
Hope it helps! BR

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect the $screenshotdir

Comment: No console output. The CLI just sits there/hangs. I can see firefox in my tasklist, so it is being called and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify protocol (`https://` or `http://`) as it is in the article you linked to:

```
# Tested with Developer Edition of Firefox
$domain = "example"
$domainName = example.com"
$screenshotdir = "C:\SO\56572800"


# This works
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList "--screenshot $screenshotdir\$domain-with-https.png", "https://$domainName" -Wait

# But doesn't work
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe " -ArgumentList " --screenshot $screenshotdir\$domain-no-https.png ", "$domainName" -Wait
```

From what I checked, if you don't specify `https://` prefix (or `http://` if applicable), it'll hang for a long time so you might have an impression that it's working.

---

As [@lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4527057/lloyd) mentioned in comments, you have to make sure that value of `$screenshotdir` is properly assigned and available to the function.

Also, it's a good practice to trim leading/trailing spaces from your command, even though in your example it still works with the spaces. I mean these ones:

```
                                                                HERE |          HERE |                                    HERE |
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " -ArgumentList " --screenshot $screenshotdir\$domain.png ", "$domainName" -Wait
```